# how can I restrict access to records that are owned by a user

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to restrict access to records that are owned by a user by filtering out recors with a certain criteria?

For example, I have Contacts set to private and I want to hide certain contact records that have a specific field value (criteria based sharing rule).  This works fine for other sales users that don't own the record, but I need to remove visibility to these records from the actual owner of the record.  Is that possible or a way to accomplish that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the owner of the Contact record to a placeholder user. Then the same mechanism the prevents other users from seeing the Contact will hide the record as well.

If required, you could also create a lookup field to track the relationship to the user who can no longer access the record.

Separately, there is a dedicated [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site for asking Salesforce related questions.